# cordova InAppPurchase Plugin gives error "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProducts' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, npm, cordova-plugins

I use [cordova in-app-purchase plugin](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) in my App, but getting error of "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProducts' of undefined"

.ts File is like:

```
window['plugins'].inAppPurchase.getProducts(productIds).then(products => {
      console.log('got products: ', JSON.stringify(products));
      self.buyProducts(products[0].productId);

    });
```

Stuck in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are using inAppPurchase class object is not right, Follow below approach to make it work. 
To add plugin run this command:
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inapppurchase`

After successfully installing and configuring the plugin. import and use the plugin in the required component as follows.

`import { InAppPurchase } from '@ionic-native/in-app-purchase/ngx';`
and inject in the constructor like this

```
constructor(
    private iap: InAppPurchase,
  ) {
        this.iap
        .getProducts(PaymentPage.PRODUCT_IDS)
        .then((products) => {
          console.log('Get products', JSON.stringify(products));                            
         })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));          
        });
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I am not using ionic for cross platform implementation